# C++: Template Function with a return type of T taking no T type arguments won't compile

Tags: c++, function, templates

Trying to call template functions that return a type `T` but that take no arguments of type `T`.

---

Here's a concrete example of what I am trying to do:

```
template <typename T>
T foo()
{
    T data = 0;
    return ( data );
}

template <typename T>
T baz( size_t length, const char * name = nullptr )
{
    (void) name;
    (void) length;
    T data = foo(); /* Compiler Error : no matching function for call to 'foo' */
    return ( data );
}

template <typename T>
T bar( size_t length = 0 )
{
    (void) length;
    return ( baz( length ) ); /* Compiler Error : no matching function for call to 'baz' */
}

int main()
{

    int a = foo(); /* no matching function for call to 'foo' */
    int b = bar(); /* no matching function for call to 'bar' */
    int c = baz(); /* no matching function for call to 'baz' */

    return (0);
}
```

I expect the compiler to infer the types and be able to recognize the function(s) I am referring to.

Comment: Type information never\* flows backward in C++. You can always determine the deduced types by looking at just a subexpression. \*(except for a few cases: overloaded functions being converted to a function pointer and implicit conversion operators)

Comment: Unrelated: rather than `(void) name;` to remove warnings, remember that you can `T baz( size_t length, const char * /*name = nullptr*/ )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a function template that does not take any arguments or the template parameter cannot be deduced from the arguments used to make the function call, the only way to invoke the function template is by being explicit about the template parameter.

Instead of

```
int a = foo();
```

you'll have to use

```
int a = foo<int>();
```

Similarly for `bar` and `baz`.